# Docker Compose with multiple Network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

Does anyone know how to properly deploy this? I keep getting a string error.
I have two apps in my compose file, i want to network one via mac-vlan for front-end and a bridge for the backend.

App Config

```
 networks:
      - backend
      - network-name:
          ipv4_address: x.x.x.x
```

Defining network

```
networks:
    network-name:
        external:
            name: network-name
    backend:
        driver: bridge
```

Error

```
services.service-name.networks contains {"network-name": {"ipv4_address": "x.x.x.x"}}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string
```

Comment: The easiest approach is to delete all of the blocks you show.  For most normal uses you shouldn't need multiple networks or to manually assign IP addresses; let all containers use the `default` network Compose provides for you, and completely ignore the container-private IP addresses.